# Matlab: Scale figures for publishing - exact dimensions and font sizes

Tags: matlab, font-size, scaling, figure

I am currently writing up a scientific thesis and am very desparate about creating figures that have the exact dimensions I want them to have. Especially the font sizes do not match.
I already googled alot and there are a bunch of guides and scripts about this topic but nothing really helped - I have not yet figured out (sorry) why my approach does not work:

```
FS=8; %font size in points (the same as in my document)
width=12; %width of figure in cm
height=4; %height of figure in cm
scatter(1:20,rand(20,1));
xlabel('X','fontsize',FS),ylabel('Y','fontsize',FS),title('X vs. Y','fontsize',FS)
%now I scale the figure and place it in the bottom left corner. The white margins around it are cropped automatically
set(gca,'units','centimeters','outerposition',[0 0 width height])
%export as .eps
print(gcf,'-depsc','test')
```

When I load test.eps into Inkscape, the figure is 10.16 x 3.529 cm large and the font sizes (of title and axis labels) are 10.
How do I get a figure with the exact scaling, especially regarding the font size?

Comment: Side note: If you are using Latex, you can take a look at the [psfrag](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) package. That allows you to replace strings in eps-figures. Hence, the replacements will be of the same font and size of the text.

Comment: You could try the [`PaperPosition`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html) figure property. From the description it seems to be doing what you are after.

Comment: @Schorsch `PaperPosition` is the trick, I once struggled with that as well and were search the web for hours. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Schorsch @patrik I have already experimented with PaperPosition, but this does not do the trick either:
`set(gcf,'paperunits','centimeters','papersize',[width height],'paperposition',[0 0 widht height]);`
When exported, the figure still is not widht x height scaled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve it as of now - it is not exactly elegant but it works...
I plot my figure and arrange and scale it in the figure window the way I want it to be scaled:

```
set(gcf,'units','centimeters','position',[0 0 width height])
```

Due to the white margins around the axes, I increase the width/height by approximate (trial and error...) values that the margins use up. I then export it:

```
export_fig(gcf,'test','-eps','-transparent')
```

And load it into Inkscape. Now I set the document properties so that the document has the exact size I want my figure to have - the figure is partly out of this frame because I increased the width/height earlier.
Then I arrange the axes to have as much white space between them as I want them to have; hopefully, everything is inside the document borders after that.
Probably the drawing is smaller than the document borders now - to ensure that it will not get expanded, messing up the scaling, when I put it in my actual document (my thesis, not the Inkscape document...), I simply create a white background that matches the document borders. Aaand done.
Except for the fontsize and fontname properties in Matlab - I have not figured out why they are not properly exported...but this is not hard to manually fix in Inkscape.

Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
FS=8; %font size in points (the same as in my document)
width=12; %width of figure in cm
height=4; %height of figure in cm
scatter(1:20,rand(20,1));
set(gca, 'fontsize', FS);
xlabel('X','fontsize',FS),ylabel('Y','fontsize',FS),title('X vs. Y','fontsize',FS)
set(gcf,'units','centimeters','position',[0 0 width height])
export_fig(gcf, 'test.pdf', '-transparent', '-nocrop')
```

The output figure is 12cm x 4cm. The font size still claims to be 10 in Inkscape, however, but it looks the same size as that in the figure. [Export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) can be downloaded from the [MATLAB file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange).

Comment: That does not work for me - my exported figure is 10.36cm x 3.89cm large. I don't get why this does not work...